# How to integrate Wordpress with Magento using FishPig?

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I tried to integrate WordPress with my Magento site using FishPig and was 95% successful. 
WP is installed at home user public_html wp and below are the settings in Magento Database Integration page.

```
Magento and WP uses different db's.  
Integration level:  Full  
Blog Route: blog  
WP Path: /home/user/public_html/wp
```

Settings at WP Admin area are:

```
WordPress Address (URL): http://domain.com/wp
Site Address (URL): http://domain.com/blog
```

The issue is, Magento admin area still shows a red exclamation mark for Blog Route.

```
Blog Route Go to the General Settings page of your WordPress Admin and set the 'Site address (URL)' field to "http://domain.com/blog"
```

Same message in the error log:

```
DEBUG (7): Go to the General Settings page of your WordPress Admin and set the 'Site address (URL)' field to 'http://domain.com/blog'
```

Any clue where I went wrong?

Comment: Clear var/cache/* and var/session/*. Also is there a message about .htaccess rewrites anywhere in the same WP page where the general settings are?

Answer (score 1):

Under the Integration tab, select 'No' for 'Integrate Theme'.

I assumed this was to integrate my magento theme with wordpress, but it is actually to integrate an existing wordpress installation theme.

If your existing installation and new installation are the same it will result in the error:

"Your integrated blog URL (http://www.yoursite/blog) matches your WordPress Site URL."

So you simply need to set this to 'No' if you only have the one wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to the WordPress Admin, select Settings > General and set the field labelled 'Site Address (URL)' to http://domain.com/blog